# Cocos2d. CCMenuItem with custom touchable region?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch, ccmenuitem

For example, in my case every button look likes a hex.
Hex pictures on these buttons can't intersect but their rects can.

Comment: Not without modifying the CCMenuItem code respectively subclassing.

Comment: thanks it will be my temporary solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new `activeArea` property of `CCMenuItem` to define your custom touchable region: see [this article](http://2sa-studio.blogspot.com/2013/01/custom-touch-area-for-ccmenuitem-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CGMutablePathRef to make non-rectangular sprite collision detection. use this in CCMenuItem. It works...See my answer in this post:[Custom touch detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333822/detect-transparent-part-on-the-sprite-in-cocos2d/12516903#12516903)