# Ignoring transparent areas of sprites in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've been stuck for literally weeks now trying to figure out how I can ignore touches to transparent areas of a sprite. I've been trying to follow pixel perfect collisions using this tutorial -- http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/fast-pixelperfect-collision-detection-cocos2d-code-1of2/ to no avail. This is currently how my code looks:

```
-(void)checkTap:(CGPoint)touch{
BOOL yesNo = NO;
if(yesNo == NO)
{
    sprTap.position = ccp(touch.x, touch.y);
}}

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

[self checkTap:location];
touchFlag = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < [sprArray count]; i++)
{
  KKPixelMaskSprite *sprite = (KKPixelMaskSprite *)[sprArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if([sprTap intersectsNode:sprite])
        {
            selectedSprite = sprite;
            touchFlag = 1;
            break;
        }
}}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

[sprTap setPosition:location];
if(touchFlag == 1)
{
  _spriteTouch = TRUE;
  [selectedSprite setPosition:location];
}
else
{
  for(int i = 0; i < [sprArray count]; i++)
  {
      KKPixelMaskSprite *sprite = (KKPixelMaskSprite *)[sprArray objectAtIndex:i];
                if([sprTap intersectsNode:sprite])
                {
                    selectedSprite = sprite;
                    touchFlag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
}}
```

The problem with this is when the bounding box of sprTap intersects with the bounding box of sprite, it moves both and since my sprites aren't perfect squares, that won't do. I also tried pixelMaskIntersectsNode but that doesn't seem to work either. How else can I ignore the touches to the transparent parts of the sprite? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CGMutablePathRef to detect transparent part:

Refer my answer in [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333822/detect-transparent-part-on-the-sprite-in-cocos2d/12516903#12516903)

Information about How to create CGPath:[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953630/cgpath-is-not-detected-properly-in-cocos2d/14954003#14954003)

For more information, [Click Here](http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/2011/the-magic-of-cgpaths/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will give it a try. I do have a question with regards to this answer though, how can I implement this if there are 2 or more sprites that can be touched?

Comment: I kind of figured out how to implement that but I am having a problem. My sprites are supposed to move depending on swipe direction. My problem is, whenever I swipe upwards, the sprites just move to the left. Why is that?

Comment: refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953630/path-is-not-detected-properly-in-cocos2d/14954003#14954003