# Sprites going the wrong way when ignoring transparent areas of image in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Following [guru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664177/guru)'s advice from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928748/ignoring-transparent-areas-of-sprites-in-cocos2d), I added this code on my init method in order to prevent touch events on transparent areas of a sprite:

```
    path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, endTouch.x, endTouch.y);
    //250(y) is the height of the path, 50(x) is the width
    //set your width and height to be the same size as the non-transparent part of your sprite
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 250);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 50, 0);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```

Then I modified my touch event like so:

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if(gameStat == TRUE)
{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint loc=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    loc=[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:loc];
    beginTouch = loc;

    for(int i = 0; i < [sprArray count]; i++)
    {
        CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)[sprArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], loc))
        {
            selectedSprite = sprite;
            //test the path
            loc = [selectedSprite convertToNodeSpace:loc];
            if (CGPathContainsPoint(path, NULL, loc, NO) ) {
                NSLog(@"inside");
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"outside");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint loc1 = [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view]];
CGPoint loc2 = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
loc2 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:loc2];
endTouch = location;

int goUp = loc2.y - loc1.y;
if(goUp > 0){
CGPoint locationPath  = [selectedSprite convertToNodeSpace:location];
        if (CGPathContainsPoint(path, NULL, locationPath, NO) ) {
            [selectedSprite setPosition:location];
            _spriteTouch = TRUE;
        }
}}
```

Now, this works great but my problem is that the sprites tend to move the wrong way. It's supposed to follow the touch swipe which would be upwards but no matter how I swipe upwards, it keeps going right instead. What am I doing wrong here? please help me.

UPDATE: I managed to figure out how to fix my code so this is already solved. I've updated my code just in case anybody else comes into the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing this

```
 loc = [selectedSprite convertToNodeSpace:loc];
```

to the following

```
 loc = [selectedSprite convertToWorldSpace:loc];
```

[EDIT: updated sample]
since the call to convertToGL: the point based is formatted to OpenGL based where:

### Coordinates

```
y+           (0,0)                  |y+
|            +------ y+      x-     |      x+
|            |               ---- (0,0) ----
|            |                      |
+ ---- x+    |                      |
(0,0)        x+                     y-
OpenGl       Cocoa Touch         Cartesian
```

Touches which origin from the screen (Cocoa Touch) does not know about the OpenGL coordinate so it needs to be converted with [Cocos2d CCDirector](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.2/interface_c_c_director.html):

> - (CGPoint) convertToGL:(CGPoint)p
>     converts a UIKit coordinate to an OpenGL coordinate Useful to convert (multi) touchs coordinates to the current layout (portrait or landscape)

Same goes other way around with

> - (CGPoint) convertToUI:(CGPoint)p
>     converts an OpenGL coordinate to a UIKit coordinate Useful to convert node points to window points for calls such as glScissor

Sometimes, I got confuse and logging (instead of breakpoint) the point determines which coordinate in effect so I can figure out the logic.

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint.position));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it but sadly, it didn't do anything. It kept printing "outside" hence, my sprites didn't move at all.

Comment: can you try logging the point and check whether its returning the correct point of your touch, like so: NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));

Comment: ah, just notice. you mention touch swipe. so i should look inside touchMoved:. have you tried converting in the touchMoved:?

Comment: converting to worldspace in the touchMoved? Yes, it didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I was able to fix it by making some adjustments to my code.

Comment: no worries buddy, if this answer helped you in finding the solution. consider accepting it so it can help others as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

In touchesMoved Method, you are doing this:-

```
loc2 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:loc2];
```

But not converting the loc1 to GL coordinates accordingly. I think you should try this:-

```
loc1 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:loc1];
```

It might help.