# CGPath is not detected properly in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cgpath

Through help and suggestions, I created a path for my sprite so that only the non-transparent parts can be touched. This is the path I came up with:

```
    path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, endTouch.x, endTouch.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 250);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 30, 0);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```

This works for all my other classes except for one. No matter where I tap, xcode keeps printing "outside" using this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [sprArray count]; i++)
{
    CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)[sprArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], location))
    {
        selectedSprite = sprite;
        location = [selectedSprite convertToNodeSpace:location];
        if (CGPathContainsPoint(path, NULL, location, NO) ) 
        {
            NSLog(@"inside");
        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"outside");
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

I can only move my sprites if I get inside the if-condition, not else but even if I tap on the actual, colored sprite, it doesn't get the path I set. Are my measurements wrong? If not, what am I doing wrong? This is similar to the image I'm trying to use...

[image: sample]

Comment: Be more detailed about the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works only if image size is same. Depending on image size calculate coordinates.

[image]

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(path,    NULL,   54, 0 ); //1: 54 = distance from left, 0 = dis fem bottom
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,   28, 34 );
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,   36, 76 );
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,   51, 104 );
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,   46, 147 );
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,   67, 147 );
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,   70, 105 );
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,   56, 66 );
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,   52, 42 );
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,   67, 20 );
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,   92, 0 );
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So if I have sprites of a different shape, I'm gonna have to create different path right?

Comment: yes, for both iphone and iPad...u may get bored by creation of this path..so if number of shapes are limited then only go for this way.

Comment: I've got a question again. What can you suggest for sprites that has animation?

Comment: not yet used CGPath for animated sprite. In worst case you can per frame specific CGPath..Please take some experts suggestion before going in this approach :(

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I'm still new in objective-c. I've started a month ago so this is really turning into a horrible headache to me.

Comment: spend some time in research...you may get best way for this problem...ALL THE BEST..