# Handing a touch on a rotated CCLayer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

After I rotate a CCLayer, my boundingBox grows, instead of rotating. Perhaps to be expected.

My issue is, I'm relying on a user touch on this layer. When the layer is rotated as in the figure on the bottom of the attached image, the clickable area increases because I'm calling:

```
if(CGRectContainsPoint(clickableLayer.boundingBox, touchLocation))
```

This causes an issue because this bounding box after rotation is covering up other things that are also clickable.

How do I only perform an action if the actual layer is touched? I want something to happen when just the green box is clicked, not the boundingBox of the layer.

Thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use CGMutablePathRef to detect transparent part:

Refer my answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333822/detect-transparent-part-on-the-sprite-in-cocos2d/12516903#12516903).

Information about How to create CGPath:[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953630/cgpath-is-not-detected-properly-in-cocos2d/14954003#14954003)

For more information, [Click Here](http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/2011/the-magic-of-cgpaths/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This thread got me to my answer: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/272336