# Ignoring touches on transparent areas cocos2dx

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I have an image of size `480x800` pixels and there is a icon on one corner which I need to place. What I want is that to ignore all touches on the transparent areas and detect only the area where the icon is.
I found a [solution in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889170/cocos2d-2-0-ignoring-touches-to-transparent-areas-of-layers-sprites/) to this problem but it just tells the code to be used. I need to know exactly where to put that code since I am a beginner and don't know much about cocos2d so I expect a step by step solution.

[Cocos2d 2.0 - Ignoring touches to transparent areas of layers/sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889170/cocos2d-2-0-ignoring-touches-to-transparent-areas-of-layers-sprites/)

Comment: add to your Object Class will be fine.

Comment: could you explain in detail?

Comment: if you got a class called Button(which could be a subclass of CCSprite), you can just add this code (rewrite using c++) to that class, and using this code together with CCTouchBegan

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `glReadPixels` because it affected by bugs in android drivers. You can translate CCTouch to CCPoint in image coordinates using `convertTouchToNodeSpace`, and read image pixel at given point.

Create CCImage from file that contains semi-transparent picture, and read one pixel at tap point; it should be {0,0,0,0} for transparent area.

Don't forget to check that tap is not outside picture, and create pixel index in `CCImage::getData()` array with formulae `unsigned index = x * imageWidth + y`.

Comment: i understand what you just said. one more thing. what if i have 3 icons in the same format as described above and now i want to detect if any icon was touched and if any icon was indeed touched, which one was it, how would you solve this?

Comment: Each icon presented by sprite, so you can get touch location in icon coordinates for each icon and than use pixel comparison. In other words, you should test that touch hits to icon rectangle and than also test if it hits non-transparent area.

Comment: this is what i am doing rite now. there is a background image of object ccsprite size 480x800. then there are 3 ccsprite objects each of size 480x800 which are the icons placed over the background. each image that has the icon is transparent from everywhere else other then where the icon is. if u could tell me how to resolve the issue now? will comparing the pixels work in this case? if so how do we get pixels from a ccsprite object and from the touched coordinates.

Comment: Create CCImage from the same resource, it will keep all pixels for this sprite.

Comment: This solution won't work correctly if the CCSprite is scaled up or down.