# Touching transparent part of Sprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using SpriteBuilder with Cocos2d v3.4
I need to detect touch on sprite ignoring touch in transparent place of CCSprite's bounding box.

[image]

I found few solutions (Physics Body, CGPath), but actually detecting transparent pixel seems the best solution.
I tried to use [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10893738) but it is very old solution and not working anymore.
Could someone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Why does this solution not work anymore ?

Comment: Did you try the code in the other post? Did you get any errors? This seems the only way to do it, unless you either want to create to CGRects (1 for the top length of the drill and 1 for the vertical handle). If these rectangles are touched, then you're ok. If you can post what your results were from testing the code, someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create 2 CGRect on the sprite and detect touch only on these rects